# SEO in what element text should be placed?

Tags: seo

I am making my web better for SEO and I came up with question:
in what element text should be placed?

```
<p></p>
<span></span>
<div></div>
```

I know that I should use each of them in different situations but I dont know in which situations...

**EDIT:**
[Example of 2 situations/doubts I encountered](http://jsfiddle.net/TwSs7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If (and only if!) it is a *paragraph* of text, use `p`.

`div` and `span` don't assume any meaning. You use them if there is no other appropriate element. The difference? `div` is used as a block element, `span` is used as an inline element.  In general, a block level element can contain other block level elements and inline elements. An inline level element can only contain other inline level elements. But there are some exceptions. [Validate](http://validator.w3.org/) your documents.

Example:

```
<div class="about">
 <p>Hi, my name is <span class="name">John Doe</span> and I like cats.</p>
</div>
```

If you are not sure which element to use (or if you are not sure if an element is really appropriate to use in a specific context), use `div` resp. `span`.

To understand the meaning of all the other elements, you should consult the HTML spec and examine carefully the definition of the particular element.

---

About your [examples in the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TwSs7/):

Example 1: Yes, the price shouldn't be enclosed in a `p`, because it's not a paragraph. If you should use `div` or `span` depens on the context of this snippet. If you'd use HTML5, I'd mark it up that way (but it's hard to tell, because it depends on the whole page content!):

```
<article>
 <a href="…"><img src="…" alt="…" /></a>
 <h1><a href="…">Table</a></h1>
 <span>RRP £4.00</span>
</article>
```

Example 2: I'd go for:

```
<article>
  <h1 id="text-title">Turtle Stool Blue</h1>
  <dl>
    <dt>Produce Code</dt>
    <dd>D060029BLU</dd>
    <dt>Price</dt>
    <dd id="text-price">RRP £4.00</dd>    
  </dl>
  <p id="text-desc">Cras sed leo. Cras vehicula aliquet libero. Integer in magna. Phasellus dolor elit, pellentesque a, facilisis non, bibendum sed, est. Nunc laoreet lectus quis massa. Mauris vestibulum, neque sed dictum eleifend, nunc risus varius orci, in consequat enim diam vel arcu. Curabitur ut odio vel est tempor bibendum. Donec felis orci, adipiscing non, luctus sit</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Well I know this basic but I got more complex (or I think it's more complex) situations. here's js fiddle with 2 of my situations. It would be nice if you can help me understand on the examples in which element I should use and why. http://jsfiddle.net/TwSs7/

Comment: @Ron: I updated my answer to refer to your examples. I think you should update your question accordingly (link/quote the jsfiddle there, too).

Comment: I am not using HTML5 therefore the dl, dt, dd and article tags dont help me..

Comment: @Ron: You _can_ use `dl` in HTML 4.01 / XHTML, too (the semantic is slightly different, though; would be worth a discussion if it is still applicable). If you don't use HTML5, you'd only have to change the `article` to `div` (and change the heading level accordingly). If you don't want to use a `dl`, you enclose the produce code in one `div` and the price in another.

Answer (score 0):

As unor says, your document should be validated.

Otherwise, the document should display well to users, and be semantically correct in the code.  Where there are overlaps in functionality like this, the real answer is it doesn't matter.  Robots will read all those elements as text, probably not boosting any priorities based on which tag they are in.